# Django: Looking for a string in the template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do I look for a django template variable in another variable?
Let's say I want to make every occurrence of {{ search_string }} in {{ body }} bold, how do I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search: {{ search_string }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for title, href, body in search_list %}
        <h4><a href={{href|safe}} target="_blank"> {{ title }} </a></h4>
    {{ body }}
 <!-- I need to make occurrences of {{ search_string }} in {{ body }} bold -->
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think we need more detail about what you're trying to do and/or why it's necessary. Based on your comment to @Exprator's answer, I think you're only way of doing that will be to modify the content of ``{{ my_variable }}`` in the view before it gets passed to the template to include the necessary css (you'd likely have to use ``mark_safe``, which may be an issue). Struggling to understand why you're trying to do it this way, and why you can't seperate the two template vars. Can you post the code?

Comment: What exactly I am trying to do: a Search Engine. I pass the content of what's in the view to the django template, as well as the string used to do the search. And I want to make every occurrence of this string_search in the content passed to django template bold.

Comment: Just edited my question, explaining better what I need and putting the code.

Comment: Thanks. You're going to need to write a custom template tag. I suggest you'd use the tag to search the ``body`` for occurrences of ``"search string"`` and then wrap those occurrences in html/css as the other answers, below. Let me know if you want a detailed answer setting out how to do this (the Django docs for "Custom Template Tag" are pretty good though).